# Pathogen and Neocomplete, Supertab, Youcompleteme; how to enable disable bundles?

Tags: vim, plugins

I use Pathogen to load my plugins at startup.

Sometimes I use `Neocomplete` plugin, sometimes `YouCompleteMe` plugin and sometimes `Supertab` to complete words and sometimes I use no completer at all.
These plugins do not work together if they are all loaded in Pathogen.

That's why I decided to create a little menu at then end of my vimrc where I can chose which completer to use (the one that I want to use is the one I disable in pathogen). I can launch it with a shortcut key.
The list g:PATHO contains the plugins to disable in pathogen:
If I chose to use Supertab --> remove Supertab from g:PATHO, save g:PATHO and reload vimrc.
If I chose to use Neocomplete --> remove Neocomplete from g:PATHO, save g:PATHO and reload vimrc.
If I chose to use Youcompleteme --> remove Youcompleteme from g:PATHO, save g:PATHO and reload vimrc.

This is what I have at the start of my _vimrc

```
  if !exists("g:PATHO")
    let g:PATHO = ['YouCompleteMe','neocomplete.vim','supertab']
  endif
  let g:pathogen_disabled = g:PATHO
```

below in my _vimrc I have this command to save global variables in my viminfo file:

```
set viminfo+=!
```

(thanks to Ingo Karkat)

g:PATHO is written in viminfo but when I reload vimrc, the variable g:PATHO is not found because viminfo is not yet read at the start of _vimrc.
When is viminfo read in _vimrc? 
How can I let pathogen read g:PATHO at vimrc startup?
(hope I made myself clear)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read `:help startup`?

1. Your `viminfo` file is read *very* late in the initialization process, *after* your `vimrc` and all your plugins are sourced, so pathogen won't be able to compare the default `g:PATHO` that you hardcoded in your `vimrc` with the one in your `viminfo`.
2. Your `viminfo` file is read only once, late in the initialization process, and will never be re-read again during the life span of your session. Reloading your `vimrc` will never trigger that re-read and neither pathogen nor any other plugin will notice the change you hoped to persist.

   You can try `:rviminfo` to re-read that file manually and autocmds on `VimEnter` or some other event but…
3. …modifying the `g:pathogen_disabled` variable during a session won't have the effect you want: it doesn't remove a plugin from your `runtimepath` and it doesn't "unsource" it either. You can reload your `vimrc` all you want with different values for that option, the result will always be the same: nothing.

What you need — beyond coming up with a convincing justification for such a weird idea or even for the fact that you have three freaking completion plugins in your config — is to find a way to effectively make the functions and variables and whatever of a specific plugin completely disappear from Vim's memory. And I believe you won't find it here.

---

As a side note, only one of the three plugins provides [built-in commands to enable/disable it](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim/blob/master/doc/neocomplete.txt#L185-L190). *That* is a sensible design choice that, if it was more universally available, would make the life of plugin hoarders a lot easier.

Comment: thanks, I use youcompleteme because it is maybe the best but sometimes I only want to use a completer in manual completion mode. You cannot do this with youcompleteme. It keeps poping-up. Neocomplete has a manual completion mode (tab key). I use supertab for p.e. spellcheck completion (but not for buffer completion, supertab doesn't have a fuzzy search). Do you know these three plugins?

Comment: YCM does manual completion. Yes I know them and I don't use them or any other alternative.

Comment: There were a few discussions in the past about manual completion but I haven't seen one person using YCM with manual completion. Have you tried it yourself? I've once read that Valloric doesnt want to adapt YCM for manual completion.

Comment: This is not to invoke manual completion only to disable YCM except the segmental triggers. See also here: https://github.com/christoomey/dotfiles/issues/79 I tested it but it doesn't manual trigger.

Comment: BTW thank you for your answer. There is i.m.o. just one possibility left, writing directly in vimrc file and restarting vim. :)